# a hashmap with multiple keys to value?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a question about hashmaps with multiple keys to value. Let's say I have (key / value )

1/a, 1/b, 1/3, 2/aa, 2/bb, 2/cc.

Would this work?

If it does, could I have a way to loop through it and display all values for only either key 1 or 2?

Answer (score 6):

You can use a map with lists as values, e.g.:

```
HashMap<Integer, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
```

Answer (score 3):

`java.util.HashMap` does not allow you to map multiple values to a single key.  You want to use one of Guava's [Multimap's](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).  Read through the interface to determine which implemented version is suitable for you.

Comment: thanks. are there any other ways without using external sources?

Answer (score 3):

A simple MultiMap would look something like this skeleton:

```
public class MultiMap<K,V>  
{
    private Map<K,List<V>> map = new HashMap<K,List<V>>();
    public MultiMap() 
    { 
        // Define constructors
    }

    public void put(K key, V value)
    {
        List<V> list = map.get(key);
        if (list == null)
        {
            list = new ArrayList<V>();
            map.put(key, list);
        }
        list.add(value);
    }

    public List<V> get(K key)
    {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    public int getCount(K key)
    {
        return map.containsKey(key) ? map.get(key).size() : 0;
    }
}
```

It cannot directly implement `Map<K,V>` because `put` can't return the replaced element (you never replace).  A full elaboration would define an `interface MultiMap<K,V>` and an implementation class, I've omitted that for brevity, as well as other methods you might want, such as `V remove(K key)` and `V get(K key, int index)`... and anything else you can think of that might be useful :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maps will handle multiple keys to one value since only the keys need be unique:
Map(key, value)

However one key to multiple values requires s multimap of a map strict of :
Map(key, list(values))

Also, whatever you use as a key really should implement a good hadhCode() function if you decide to use a HashMap and/or HashSet

Edit: had to use() instead of <> because my mobile or sof's mobile site editor clobbered the <> symbols....odd